# Accessing a method outside of the project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working in a solution which contains multiple projects. I need to access a method from one project in a different project. We have a separate project for handling incoming packets and updating the local data and then from this i need to access a method in the main application project (which displays a custom notification to the user)

In the main application i have a method with the following signature

```
Public Sub NotifyRemoved(ByVal message As String)
```

In the packet handling project i have tried using an invoke to call the method like so:

removedItems is a list of strings.

"MainForm" is the class the above method is within.

```
For Each removed As String In removedItems
    Dim newType As Type = Type.GetType("MainForm")
    Dim newConstructor As ConstructorInfo = newType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
    Dim newClassObject As Object = newConstructor.Invoke(New Object() {})

    Dim newMethod As MethodInfo = newType.GetMethod("NotifyRemoved")
    newMethod.Invoke(newClassObject, New Object() {removed & " has been removed from list"})

Next
```

When i run this through debug the Type.GetType() method returns nothing and therefor throws an exception on the next line... I have tried some other ways using events etc. but all the method i can find seem to need direct access between the two classes.

any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add a reference to the project containing MainForm, then call it directly using `ProjectName.MainForm`

Comment: Why are you trying to use reflection instead of just adding a project reference?  (Note that I'm not saying this is necessarily the correct approach architecturally.  Adding a reference to a UI-based project is suspect.  But there isn't enough information in the question to really conclude that.  In general, when you need to reference code, you *add a reference* to that code.)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Reference to the project with the .dll from the other project.

Project | Add reference | Browse (to find .dll )

Once it has been added you can then reference the Projects Routine by Project.Class.Routine

Comment: If the two projects are in the same solution, adding a project reference would be preferable to adding a DLL reference.  (Even if they're not in the same solution, you at least don't want to add a DLL reference directly to the build output but rather to a more controlled location.)  File locking on build output can cause problems in Visual Studio (or any environment) if you're referencing that build output.